# Rails 3 & Endless Pagination Issue, JS is not updating DOM with partial and not throwing any errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am having an issue following Ryan Bates Endless Pagination tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised

My coffee script is working ok to fetch the results, however my index.js.erb code, the code that actually updates the DOM, is not working - nothing gets updated in the DOM nor is there any JS errors.

Here is the code:

```
<% @images.each do |image_url| -%>
      $('.thumbnails').append('<%= render :partial => "/images/partials/thumbnail", :locals => { :image_url => image_url } %>');
<% end -%>
```

Here are the logs:

```
  Rendered images/partials/_thumbnail.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered images/partials/_thumbnail.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered images/partials/_thumbnail.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered images/partials/_thumbnail.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

It looks like nothing is actually getting rendered on the page, can anyone see why this might be happening?

Thanks!

EDIT

_thumbnail.html.erb

```
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<%= image_url %>" class="grouped_elements">
      <img data-src="holder.js/160x120" src="<%= image_url %>">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: what's in `_thumbnail.html.erb`? looks like it's getting rendered just fine.

Comment: is there an element with `thumbnails` class on the page?

Comment: added _thumbnail.html.erb to OP. No thumbnails class on the page

Answer (score 0):

I was trying endless pagination at that time i found the wiki of kaminari gem with endless pagination and made my work to easy.......

check this link and i am defiantly sure that u would over come this issue.

[Kaminari+jquery+ajax(endless pagination)](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, the problem was that I was not escaping the JavaScript

The solution was to change:

```
$('.thumbnails').append('<%= render :partial => "/images/partials/thumbnail", :locals => { :image_url => image_url } %>');
```

to

```
$('.thumbnails').append('<%= j render :partial => "/images/partials/thumbnail", :locals => { :image_url => image_url } %>');
```

Note the "j" before render - once I added this, it worked.